# Cannot run RandomForestClassifier from spark ML on a simple example

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have tried to run the experimental `RandomForestClassifier` from the `spark.ml` package (version 1.5.2). The dataset I used is from the `LogisticRegression` example in the [Spark ML guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html).

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// Prepare training data from a list of (label, features) tuples.
val training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
  (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
  (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
)).toDF("label", "features")

val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()

val model = rf.fit(training)
```

And here is the error, I obtain:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RandomForestClassifier was given input with invalid label column label, without the number of classes specified. See StringIndexer.
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.train(RandomForestClassifier.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.train(RandomForestClassifier.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:90)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:63)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:65)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:67)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:69)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:71)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:73)
    at <init>(<console>:75)
    at .<init>(<console>:79)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

The problem appears when the function tries to compute the number of classes in the column `"label"`.

As you can see at line 84 in the [source code of RandomForestClassifier](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/RandomForestClassifier.scala), the function calls the `DataFrame.schema` function with parameter `"label"`. This call is OK and returns a `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField` object. 
Then, the function `org.apache.spark.ml.util.MetadataUtils.getNumClasses` is called. As it does not return the expected output, an exception is raised at line 87.

After a quick glance at [`getNumClasses` source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/util/MetadataUtils.scala), I suppose that the error is due to the fact that the data in colmun `"label"` are neither `BinaryAttribute` neither `NominalAttribute`. **However, I do not know how to fix this problem.**

**My question:**

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks a lot for reading my question and for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's first fix the import to remove ambiguity

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorIndexer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineStage}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
```

I'll use the same data you used :

```
val training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
  (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
  (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
)).toDF("label", "features")
```

and then create Pipeline Stages :

```
val stages = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[PipelineStage]()
```

1. For classification, re-index classes :

```
val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("label").setOutputCol("indexedLabel").fit(training)
```

2. Identify categorical features using VectorIndexer

```
val featuresIndexer = new VectorIndexer().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("indexedFeatures").setMaxCategories(10).fit(training)
stages += featuresIndexer

val tmp = featuresIndexer.transform(labelIndexer.transform(training))
```

3. Learn Random Forest

```
val rf = new RandomForestClassifier().setFeaturesCol(featuresIndexer.getOutputCol).setLabelCol(labelIndexer.getOutputCol)

stages += rf
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages.toArray)

// Fit the Pipeline
val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(tmp)

val results = pipelineModel.transform(training)

results.show

//+-----+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
//|label|      features|indexedFeatures|rawPrediction|probability|prediction|
//+-----+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
//|  1.0| [0.0,1.1,0.1]|  [0.0,1.0,2.0]|   [1.0,19.0]|[0.05,0.95]|       1.0|
//|  0.0|[2.0,1.0,-1.0]|  [1.0,0.0,0.0]|   [17.0,3.0]|[0.85,0.15]|       0.0|
//|  0.0| [2.0,1.3,1.0]|  [1.0,3.0,3.0]|   [14.0,6.0]|  [0.7,0.3]|       0.0|
//|  1.0|[0.0,1.2,-0.5]|  [0.0,2.0,1.0]|   [1.0,19.0]|[0.05,0.95]|       1.0|
//+-----+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

**References:** Concerning the step 1. and 2. for those who want more details on *Feature transformers*, I advice you to read the official documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/ml-features.html#feature-transformers).

Comment: @zero323 what do you think? I'm not sure about the Pipeline usage. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! Could you detail a bit what do the `StringIndexer` and the `VectorIndexer` do? Or point me to somewhere it is explained. I have a lot of difficulties to find documentation on this. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't a computer access anymore for today. I'm writing from my phone now. But I'm sure that you might fight very useful documentation concerning the StringIndexer and the VectorIndexer on the official documentation page. Look for MLlib guide and Feature engineering or something like that.

Comment: Also if this answer solves your problem, please accept it so other might get use of it! Thanks :)

Comment: @eliasah I am not convinced about `VectorIndexer`  but `StringIndexer`  looks OK. It can be handled only by using metadata but it is not exactly an obvious approach :)

Comment: You ` tmp` variable can be skipped, as `featuresIndexer` and `labelIndexer` are already applied via the `Pipeline`. `pipeline.fit` is then applied to `training` rather than to `tmp`

Comment: To everyone - like me - wondering, what's going on the code given by eliasah, here is a documentation page about Feature Tramsformers in spark.ml: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/ml-features.html#feature-transformers

Comment: @Pop: You don't actually need the featuresIndexer here, right? I believe that converts categorical features to a numeric index, but in your case, your features are already numeric.

Comment: I'd really love to know how to solve this without the Pipeline.  This solution doesn't help me understand the root issue.

Comment: @Larsenal what is the root problem for you ?