# Issue in denoting negative numbers as a category for Random Forest algorithm in PySpark

Tags: python, encoding, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

**This question is in continuation to my another question at** [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981740/issue-in-encoding-non-numeric-feature-to-numeric-in-spark-and-ipython)

I am working on `Random Forest algorithm` for `classification` in `Spark MLlib` using `PySpark`. My sample `dataset` looks like this:

```
Level1,Male,New York,New York,352.888890
Level1,Male,San Fransisco,California,495.8001345
Level2,Male,New York,New York,-495.8001345
Level1,Male,Columbus,Ohio,165.22352099
Level3,Male,New York,New York,495.8
Level4,Male,Columbus,Ohio,652.8
Level5,Female,Stamford,Connecticut,495.8
Level1,Female,San Fransisco,California,495.8001345
Level3,Male,Stamford,Connecticut,-552.8234
Level6,Female,Columbus,Ohio,7000
```

As you can see the fields are in `non-numeric` format and so require `encoding` before being passed to the model. The last value in each row is a `numeric` field in `string` format(`unicode`) with some of the values having `-` sign before them. Here whenever the `features` are say `Level1,Male,New York,New York` then prediction will be `352.888890`. So `352.888890` becomes a category rather than just a numeric value.I wrote this code, where I read the data and form a `training_set` `RDD`. I then `encode` the `non-numeric` field and then form the `RDD` of `LabeledPoint` before passing it to the model for classification. This is my current code:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer as DV
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler 

from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest, RandomForestModel

def extract(line):

    return (line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4].lstrip('-'))

input_file = sc.textFile('file1.csv').zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (line,rownum): rownum>0).map(lambda (line, rownum): line)

input_data = (input_file
    .map(lambda line: line.split(","))
    .filter(lambda line: len(line) >1 )
    .map(extract)) # Map to tuples

# Divide the input data in training and test set with 80%-20% ratio
(training_data, test_data) = input_data.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])

# the column in training_data which is label - a numeric field in string format
label_col = "x4"

# converting RDD to dataframe
training_data_df = training_data.toDF(("x0","x1","x2","x3","x4"))


# Indexers encode strings with doubles
string_indexers = [
   StringIndexer(inputCol=x, outputCol="idx_{0}".format(x))
   for x in training_data_df.columns if x != label_col
]

# Assembles multiple columns into a single vector
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["idx_{0}".format(x) for x in training_data_df.columns if x != label_col],
    outputCol="features"
)


pipeline = Pipeline(stages=string_indexers + [assembler])
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData_df_1)
indexed = model.transform(trainingData_df_1)

label_points = (indexed
    .select(col(label_col).cast("double").alias("label"), col("features"))
    .map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features)))

feature1 = training_data.map(lambda x: x[0]).distinct().collect()
feature2 = training_data.map(lambda x: x[1]).distinct().collect()
feature3 = training_data.map(lambda x: x[2]).distinct().collect()
feature4 = training_data.map(lambda x: x[3]).distinct().collect()
label_set = training_data.map(lambda x: x[4]).distinct().collect()

model_classifier = RandomForest.trainClassifier(label_points,numClasses=len(label_set),categoricalFeaturesInfo={0: len(feature1), 1: len(feature2), 2: len(feature3),3: len(feature4)},
                                 numTrees=50, featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                 impurity='gini', maxDepth=10, maxBins=max([len(feature1),len(feature2),len(feature3),len(feature4)]))
```

When I run this code I get error as `ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GiniAggregator given label -495.8001345 but requires label is non-negative.`

The problem is the some `label` values is `negative numeric`. How can I use `negative numeric` values to denote a category and not a number?

Answer (score 0):

In Spark Source Code, there are Gini Impurity logic checking the label need in the range between 0 and numClasses, see below source code

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/impurity/Gini.scala

After do some research, I found some one point out the label which cause problem need be transformed to the range that Gini Impurity could handle properly

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Random-Forest-Error-td23847.html

Hope this can help