# Create LabeledPoint from rdd data which has both strings and numbers - PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have lines like this in my data:

```
0,tcp,http,SF,181,5450,0,0,0.5,normal.
```

I want to use decision tree algorithm for training. I couldn't create LabeledPoints, so I want to try HashingTF for strings but I couldn't handle it. "normal" is my target label. How can I create a LabeledPoint RDD data to use in pyspark? Also, Label for LabeledPoint requires double, should I just create some double values for labels or should it be hashed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33982962/1560062

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with the solution.

First of all, Spark's Decision tree classifier has already a parameter for this: `categoricalFeaturesInfo`. In the pyspark api documentation:

> **categoricalFeaturesInfo** - Map from categorical feature index to number of categories. Any feature not in this map is treated as continuous.

However, before doing this, we first should simply replace the strings to numbers for pypsark to understand them.

Then we create for the above example data `categoricalFeaturesInfo` as in the definition like this:

```
categoricalFeaturesInfo = {1:len(feature1), 2:len(feature2), 3:len(feature3), 9:len(labels)}
```

Simply, first ones are the indexes of the categorical features and the second ones are the number of categories in that feature.

Note that converting strings to numbers is enough for the trainer algorithm but if you declare the categorical features like this, it would train faster.